# In dotnet core, is it possible to create a library project that does not reference a standard target framework?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5, csproj

I'm looking to create a C# DLL that does not reference the `netstandardX.X` or `netX.X` target frameworks directly but instead references the specific libraries that these frameworks use. Is there a way to create a csproj that skips these references?

I want to create a csproj like this that will be enough to compile a library containing a POCO class.

The csproj looks like so:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<!--    <PropertyGroup>-->
<!--        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>-->
<!--    </PropertyGroup>-->

    Some References Here...
</Project>
```

The class would be very simple:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ThingDoer
    {
        int DoThing() {
           return 42;
        }
    }
}
```

What would be needed to get this to compile in dotnet core without un-commenting the `<TargetFramework>` section?

Comment: What is issue if you keep TargetFramework ? Is there any specific reason for not to use it  ?

Comment: @dotnetstep There is no issue with it and I would never recommend doing this. The end goal is to reproduce a stripped down dll that exposes some of the netstandard API while replacing other parts with empty calls.

Comment: @Dschroer so you want to create a custom netstandard.dll / mscorlib.dll? if you ever reference that dll from a project that acutally targets a framework, it will also reference these apis and you can't really replace these API calls with a custom code

Comment: @MartinUllrich Is there a way that would be possible to wrap them using generated code? I know its not very scalable but even just the base would be enough.

Comment: A custom netstandard,dll or mscorelib.dll would be ideal but any way to restrict access to certain APIs within them would do the trick.